# How to create a list of currently imported modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two different .py files both in the same directory - `Setup.py` & `Main.py`. In `Setup.py` I have the following function definition.

```
def imported_modules(send_to_reqs = False,append_mod = True) :
    '''
    inputs: 
    - send_to_reqs, boolean, optional, default true:
        - If true, function will return a dictionary keys = modules, values = version that has been imported
        - If false, function will write to requirements text, 
    - append_mod, boolean, optional, default False:
        - If True, function will append to requirements
        - If False, fucntion will overwrite requirements    
    '''
    import sys 
    # gets list of modules imported
    modules = list(set(sys.modules) & set(globals()))
    modules_dict = {}
    #iterates through the list of modules and appends a dictionary with the verison 
    for module_name in modules:
        module = sys.modules[module_name]
        modules_dict[module_name] =  getattr(module, '__version__','unknown')
    #writes to the reqs document 
    if send_to_reqs == True:
        if append_mod == True:
            # opens the requirements text as append only and appends the modules to it 
            f = open("Requirements.txt","a+")
            for key, value in modules_dict.items() :
                f.writelines(str(key + ":" + value + "\n" ))
            f.close()
            return "Requirements.txt has been updated with latest modules."
        else:
            # opens requirements an removes existing modules and attaches new ones.
            # opens as read only and saves the previous data. 
            f = open('Requirements.txt', 'r')
            data = f.read()
            f.close()
            import re, datetime
            # substitutes the last updated entry with currents date and time 
            data = re.sub("(Last updated:) (\d*-\d*-\d* \d*:\d*:\d*.\d*)","Last updated: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()), data)
            #searchs for the position of --END and gets location
            a = re.search(r'(.*?)(?=--END)',data)
            # uses location to get 
            updated_header = data[:int(a.end()+6)]
            for key ,value in modules_dict.items() :
                updated_header = updated_header  + key + ":" + value + "\n" 
            f = open('Requirements.txt', 'w')
            f.write(updated_header)
            f.close()
            return "Requirements file has been replaced."
    else :
        return modules_dict
```

My function goes through some logic but essentially gets a dictionary of imported modules and writes it to a file.

In my `Main.py` I basically just import a bunch of modules to test out the function. Then I try to import the function and see what results come out. 
Everytime I execute I get a blank list where I expect to get a list of  (numpy, win32com , bs4, scipy, Setup) since the first thing I do is import those modules.

```
import numpy, win32com , bs4, scipy, Setup
send_to_reqs = True
append_mod = True
a = Setup.imported_modules(send_to_reqs, append_mod)
print(a)
```

When I was creating the code I had the definition of the function inside of `Main.py` and once I had it working I moved out to `Setup.py` but now it always prints out a blank dictionary. Can anyone help my trouble shoot my code? why does it work when its define in the same .py file but when I write it into another .py file but in the same directory and import the function then it doesn't work? here is the part of the function that does the work of creating the dictionary

```
import sys 
# gets list of modules imported
modules = list(set(sys.modules) & set(globals()))
modules_dict = {}
#iterates through the list of modules and appends a dictionary with the version 
for module_name in modules:
     module = sys.modules[module_name]
     modules_dict[module_name] =  getattr(module, '__version__','unknown')
```